# Using Lazy<T> to create Singleton in IIS environment

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, singleton

We are trying to use a Singleton in an IIS environment with a WCF service.

We are following the recommendation in the sixth version in this link http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

```
    private static readonly Lazy<VedtaksbehandlingRuleService> lazy = new Lazy<VedtaksbehandlingRuleService>(() => new VedtaksbehandlingRuleService());

    public static VedtaksbehandlingRuleService Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private VedtaksbehandlingRuleService()
    {
        m_Container = StaticServiceContainer.Instance;
        logger = m_Container.Resolve<ILoggerUtility>();
        InitRuleService();
    }
```

Called using:

```
VedtaksbehandlingBusObjResponse resp = VedtaksbehandlingRuleService.Instance.BehandleVedtak(req);
```

When we try this code in a unit test it works fine.

When we deploy it to IIS, it works fine for the first caller, which can call the WCF service several times without error.

But if another client calls the service they get an exception with the following text:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="nb-NO">Tjenestekallet vedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjon feilet</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
            <s:Detail>
                <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
                    <InnerException>
                        <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
                        <InnerException i:nil="true" />
                        <Message>Failure to create a Deployment Manager Server Manager  for 'VedtaksbehandlingRuleServiceDManager'</Message>
                        <StackTrace>
                            Server stack trace:     at com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManager.createDeploymentManagerServerManagers(NdDeploymentManagerConfig config) at
                            com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManager.configure() at
                            com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManager.createDeploymentManager  (NdDeploymentManagerConfig deploymentManagerConfig) at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Regelserver.DManager..ctor(String dManagerConfig) at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Regelserver.RuleServerFactory.CreateRulesServer[T](String serverConfig, String dmanagerConfig, ILoggerUtility logger) at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.VedtaksbehandlingRuleService.CreateRuleServer() at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.VedtaksbehandlingRuleService.&lt;.cctor&gt;b__0() at 
                            System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()


                            Exception rethrown at [0]: at
                            com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManager.createDeploymentManagerServerManagers(NdDeploymentManagerConfig config) at
                            com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManager.configure() at
                            com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManager.createDeploymentManager(NdDeploymentManagerConfig deploymentManagerConfig) at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Regelserver.DManager..ctor(String dManagerConfig) at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Regelserver.RuleServerFactory.CreateRulesServer[T](String serverConfig, String dmanagerConfig, ILoggerUtility logger) at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.VedtaksbehandlingRuleService.CreateRuleServer() at
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.VedtaksbehandlingRuleService.&lt;.cctor&gt;b__0() at
                            System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at
                            System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at  
                            XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.vedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjon(vedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjonRequest1 request)
                        </StackTrace>
                        <Type>com.blazesoft.server.deploy.manager.NdDeploymentManagerException</Type>
                    </InnerException>
                    <Message>Tjenestekallet vedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjon feilet</Message>
                    <StackTrace>
                        at    
                        XXX.Liv.Pensjon.Forretningstjenester.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.Vedtaksbehandlingstjeneste.vedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjon(vedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjonRequest1 request) at 
                        SyncInvokevedtaRefusjonskravOgBeregnPensjon(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
                        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs) at
                        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc) at
                        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc) at
                        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc) at 
                        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
                    </StackTrace>
                    <Type>System.Exception</Type>
                </ExceptionDetail>
            </s:Detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

We have not set the instancing mode, so it should be per call. The service is per call, but lower down in the stack we have a class that is used to access a rules engine, that must be a singleton

Anyone have an idea what is causing this problem, or have a better solution?

Comment: Why would you need a lazy per-call singleton? What problem does it solve, that a normally constructed non-singleton object would not solve?

Comment: @nvoigt or indeed, for that matter, if a singleton is desirable, would a non-lazy simple singleton work fine? i.e. `private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();` - there is currently nothing in the code that warrants the overhead of `Lazy<T>`

Comment: `static` variables on IIS are shared across AppDomain, so it's not per call here.

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: @MarcGravell: or... why not make the class static?

Comment: @Steven indeed, that's a fair question; the main times for wanting a singleton (rather than a static class) are where the singleton implements an interface (or similar) - which isn't the case here

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji please can you post the *full* exception message, including any `.InnerException` information.

Comment: Now with full exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Lazy<T>` is at fault - it will create a singleton instance per `AppDomain` as expected.

Perhaps your issue is the IIS hosting:

1. Your application pool may be configured to spawn multiple worker processes => multiple appdomains => now you have multiple instances of singleton.
2. Perhaps something is causing your app pool to recycle => it will create new AppDomain => now you again have multiple instances of singleton.
3. IIS generally creates one AppDomain per application configured for that app pool. However,  in some special cases it may create multiple app domains.
4. Your IoC container may be creating app domains (however, with default security IIS may not allow that)

So essence is that you may have to verify whether multiple app domains are created. You can use `Process Explorer` to inspect w3wp.exe. Go to properties > .NET assemblies - you will see all the appdomains created in the worker process.

If you really want singleton behavior, you may want to reconsider you WCF hosting mechanism.

PS: default instancing mode is per session - not per call.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with your approach but just to solve your problem - if what you need is a per call object (static is shared for the whole AppDomain) then make it ThreadStatic, provide a Clear() method to it and call it on EndRequest event. That way no 2 separate calls will share the object and you get your "lazy" behavior.